# Push git branch

Tags: git

Hi guys I have a question.

At the moment I have this Branchs f.e. :

```
DEV*
BRANCH1
BRANCH2
```

DEV is the main branch. Now I need to create another branch and so I create a branch3

```
DEV
BRANCH1
BRANCH2
BRANCH3*
```

I work on this branch and then I want to push on git. (I don't finish to work in this branch but I want to save what I have done) Can I push even if I'm in Branch3?
 Or I should turn in the DEV branch make a "merge" and then push?

Thank you, I'm new in this world .

Comment: _"There If I want to push, can I?"_ - sure, but do you know why and what you want to push? What are you trying to do by pushing?

Comment: Its unclear what you're asking

Comment: I have edited the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create the branch from `DEV` branch, then the head of `DEV` and `BRANCH3` is at the same commit. so you can just push the new branch as follows.

```
git push -u origin BRANCH3
```

If you have committed anything to `BRANCH3` after creating it then that change will be pushed, but if you have committed anything to `DEV` after creating the branch that change will not be pushed unless you merge `DEV` to `BRANCH3`

Comment: Ok so I can push the Branch3 without problem,  even if I'm not in the DEV branch?
At the moment I always turn back to DEV, merge and then Push

Comment: you can directly push to BRANCH3, that will act as a separate branch, you only have to merge DEV to BRANCH3, if your new changes in DEV needs to be reflected on BRANCH3 only